# Number of sales in a specific timeframe

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to answer the following question with the following table -
**Number of visitors who visited the website in July 2021?**

● Table name: VISITOR_TABLE

- VISITOR_ID → unique ID representing a visitor
- VISIT_ID → unique ID representing a visit
- VISIT_DATETIME → timestamp representing when the visit happened ○ DEMO_VIDEO_WATCHES → yes/no flag representing whether the visitor watched the demo video

my code is as follows:

```
SELECT SUM( DISTINCT VISITOR_ID)
FROM VISITOR_TABLE 
WHERE VISIT_DATETIME IN
( SELECT TIMESTAMP("2021-07"
FROM VISITOR_TABLE  );
```

Is there anything I am not considering enough to answer this question?

Comment: Can't you answer your own question by looking at the results of your SELECT? You have access to the data, and we don't, which means that you're better able to answer this question. Hint: SUM() is not the same as COUNT() and sub SELECTs aren't always necessary, and you can't SELECT a TIMESTAMP that is only a year and month, which is not a valid TIMESTAMP. There is no such date as 2021-07. You may want to think about how something can be BETWEEN two dates.

Comment: If you want an helpful answer, you need to provide sample data and required outcome, otherwise you'll get some guesses only that might be correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamps (of beginning and end of the month) to limit a query only to exaxct month

```sql
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT VISITOR_ID)
FROM VISITOR_TABLE 
WHERE 
VISIT_DATETIME BETWEEN 
TIMESTAMP '2021-07-01' AND 
TIMESTAMP '2021-07-01' + interval '1 MONTH - 1 MICROSECOND'
```

This query should be OK if timestamp is without timezone.

Comment: `DATE_TRUNC('month', TIMESTAMP '2021-07-01 00:00:00')` can be simplified to `TIMESTAMP '2021-07-01 00:00:00'` or even `TIMESTAMP '2021-07-01'`

Comment: Yes, I amend a query to make it more readable. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Use a range condition:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT visitor_id)
FROM visitor_table 
WHERE visit_datetime >= date '2021-07-01'
  and visit_datetime < date '2021-08-01'
FROM visitor_table
```

To get the *number* of visits you need to use `count()` not the sum of the values.

Comment: It can be tricky to build second date especialy in December

Comment: Why would this be any different in December?

Comment: `visit_datetime >= date '2021-12-01'   and visit_datetime < date '2022-01-01'`